# What does the Deploy checkbox in Visual Studio's configuration manager do for SSDT SQL projects?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

SSDTs are one of the rare cases when the Deploy checkboxes are enabled in the Configuration Manager:

[image: Configuration Manager in Visual Studio showing SSDT projects with Deploy checkboxes circled]

What does ticking Deploy there actually do?  Is it related to the publishing of the build results to a SQL server?